Encountering Issue on VM1: System.InvalidOperationException – IDX20803: Unable to Obtain Configuration from 'System.String
We have two servers, VM1 and VM2, where we have hosted our web application and API, and we are using a load balancer. For authentication and authorization, we are utilizing IdentityServer4. But, we are currently facing an error on VM1. Please refer to the attached image for the error details. 
The same is working fine in VM2. Are we missing something?

Could you possibly share the code that throws exception? I guess it might be issue with application settings, that they are incorrectly populated for VM1

Post the code and exception as text. Images can't be copied, tested or googled.

It seems to me like you're making a HTTP call to an external service and reading the result without checking the response code. Always check that the given response is successful before continuing. Further down in the stack trace we see that it's a timeout, can VM1 reach the service?

The problem has been resolved, the root cause is we missed adding DNS entry to the host file.
